# I have a Data Table in which i have a column with decimal values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Data Table with a column of decimal values. 
I should bind it to a drop down list where the drop down list should display the values of that decimal values in percentage without "%" symbol.I tried the following code in C#.

```
DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:0%}";
```

0.981 is displayed as 98% in DropDown list , how should I write it to avoid % symbol such that only 98 will get displayed.

Comment: have you tried remove the % from your binding expression?

`DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:0}";`

Comment: Why not simply `"{0:D}"` for decimal values?

Comment: @MohammedElSayed This will probably round up the `0.981` and generate `1`

Comment: Yes as Soner Gönül said it will generate 0 and 1 only. Thank You

Comment: DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:D}"; throws an Format specifier was invalid. Any way Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `"%"` custom specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierPct) multiples your value with `100` and uses [`PercentSymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentsymbol(v=vs.110).aspx) of your `CurrentCulture`. That means your `CurrentCulture` has `%` as a `PercentSymbol` and this custom speficier has to use it.

As a solution, you can `Clone` your `CurrentCulture` and set `PercentSymbol` to empty string and you can use *that* culture for your `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` properties.

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol = "";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = clone;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = clone;
```

now when you do that `DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:0%}";`, you will get `98` not `98%`

Comment: @HariPrakash Glad to help.